# Understanding tail recursion with stated data types

Tags: recursion, f#, algebraic-data-types

So I understand recursion relatively well, however in F# with the ability to create your own sets of data types I am not comprehending how to write a function to reference that particular scenario. Thanks for any help

```
type 'element mylist = PEANUT | BUTTER of 'element * 'element mylist
```

```
let exampleList = BUTTER (1, BUTTER (2, BUTTER (3, PEANUT)))
```

Attempting to write a tail recursive function that reverses this list?

Here is how I would write it traditionally

```
let rec helper a b =
      match a with
        | [] -> b
        | h::t -> helper t (h::b)

    let rev L = helper L []
```

Now here is what I've been attempting:

```
let rec tailrevMylist a L =
      match a with
      | [] -> []
      | PEANUT::t -> tailrevMylist t (BUTTER::L)
 

    let revMylist L =
      tailrevMylist  L []
```

*** BEGIN UPDATES/CHANGES ***

```
let rec tailrevMylist a b =
      match a with
      | PEANUT -> b
      | h::t -> tailrevMylist BUTTER (a, b)
 

    let revMylist L =
      tailrevMylist  L []
```

Still getting incorrect types -- attempted to use CONS instead of h but cannot due it expecting a union.
*** END UPDATES ***

however when I try and run `revMylist exmapleList` I get an error due to the function expecting a `'a mylist list` but having type `int mylist` in my test. I need to get the function to expect an `int mylist`.

*** SOLUTION ***

```
let rec tailrevMyList a b  =
      match a with
        | PEANUT -> b
        | BUTTER (head, tail) -> (tailrevMyList tail (BUTTER (head, b)))
 

    let revMylist L = tailrevMyList L PEANUT
```

Comment: Please don't edit the question in ways that invalidate existing answers. If you need to clarify something you can of course add to it, but changing specifics referenced by answers often leads to confusion or outright misinformation.

Comment: apologies @glennsl I was working with someone else who said utilizing the other variable names would make it easier to comprehend. I commented my changes when updating the post.

Comment: No worries. I do agree with them, and as long as the answer is changed as well that's not a problem. The other changes were more problematic.

Comment: As for the error you now have, I'm not sure what you mean by "union" but I see you've removed a set of parentheses that will cause trouble, and still have an instance of the empty list being used.

Comment: The error I'm getting is a type error related to `h::t -> tailrevMylist Butter (a,b)` 

"This expression was expected to have type " 'a mylist " but here has type " b list ". I have tried putting CONS rather than h to create `CONS::t` but that results in no changes. So I am unsure of how to alter my matching to expect the generic a mylist.

Comment: `h::t` is a list pattern (as is `CONS::t`). Look at the rules again. The second rule tells you exactly how to transform this. You have to replace every instance of `[]` and `a::b`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of a list is essentially:

```
type 'a list = [] | :: of 'a * 'a list
```

which you might notice looks very similar to your definition of `mylist`. The only difference is the use of `[]` in place of `PEANUT` and `::` in place of `BUTTER`, with `::` also being an infix operator.

You might also notice that this means you're mixing `list` and `mylist` constructors in ways that make very little sense. So instead of trying to fix your current implementation I'll just tell you how to mechanically translate your `helper` function to use `mylist` by applying a couple of very simple rules:

1. Replace `[]` with `PEANUT`.
2. Replace `a :: b` with `BUTTER (a, b)`.

That's really all there is to it. So instead of just giving you the answer I'll leave it to you to derive it yourself using these rules. Good luck!